# How are Request, Response, Cookie handled in react native expo exactly?

Tags: react-native, cookies, mobile, expo, fetch

I have a Django backend. Upon fetch (authenticating), I get a response from Django with set-cookie. I did not do anything with the token. As shown here:

```
export const login = async (username, password) => {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  };
  const body = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  };
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(body);
  
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',        
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonData,  
  };
  

  const resp = await fetch("http://ip:port/login/", requestOptions);
  const data = await resp.json();
  return data
};
```

But when I send the following request with my fetch function:

```
export const getCurUser = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch("http://ip:port/curuser/");
    const data = await resp.json();
    return data.cur
};
```

Note I did not pass anything in my header (nor handled the set-cookie earlier). However, when I look at the request obj on Django, the request contains a lot more information. Especially the Cookie, with the `sessionid` and `csrftoken` inside it.

I understand the lib probably does a lot of heavy lifting for you when creating the request. Or handle the response like how the cookie is set without me doing anything.

BUT, The question is, which part exactly were these added to the header? Expo?? React Native?? Or that `fetch` is actually invoking the native Network API on whichever native device it is? And the ios or Android will add the header by looking at the app's storage.

And I assume the cookie is stored in some sort of 'local storage', but how would I be able to get the cookie myself? (I want to check if the cookie even exists upon launching the app). I know there are libs like asyncStorage. But why use it if there is something already handling the cookie? Like in my case (But IDK what is actually handling the cookie).

So the app gets a response with "set-cookie", which part is responsible for handling the cookie? React Native? Expo?

Hopefully, this is not a dumb question. I am so confused :(

Comment: React Native uses okhttp3client internally (on android)